# How to find longest run in an array and put parentheses around it and all other runs in the array? APCSA

Tags: java, computer-science

The task is: Write a program that generates a sequence of 20 random die tosses (values 1 - 6).  The user will be asked if they want to see all runs or the largest run.  The array will then be printed designating the run by including them in parentheses.

I have tried my best to make methods to accomplish this task, but I am confused on how to add the parentheses after finding the run and finding runs greater than a length of 2. I also tried to find other programs such as mine online, but I was unable to find assistance in my issues of being able to put the parentheses around runs and finding all runs.

Example of finding all runs: 1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5 5 5) 6 3 1
Example of finding longest run: 1 2 5 5 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 5 5 5 5 6 3 1

Here is my code so far:

import java.util.*;
public class RunGenerator {

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
static int max = 6;
static int min = 1;


public static void randomNumbers(int[]array)// generates the 20 random numbers from the die tosses using Math.random
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int)Math.random()* (max-min +1) + min;
    }
}

public static int findRun(int[]array)// finds runs among the array and returns the run surrounded by parentheses
{

    for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int currentValue = array[i++];
        int lastValue = array[i];
        if(array[i] == array[i+1]) //checks to see if the element is equal to _____
        {
            System.out.println("(");
            
            while(lastValue == currentValue) //while the two elements are equal, we do not close the parentheses
            {
                count++; //what do I do in here to check for further length??
            }
        
            System.out.println(")");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(i + " " + (i+1) );
        }
    
    }
    
    
}

public static int findLargestRun(int[]array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == array[i++]) //checks to see if the element is equal to the adjacent element
        {
            
            while(array[i] == array[i++]) //while the two elements are equal, we do not close the parentheses
            {
                
            }
            System.out.println("(" + i);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(i + " " + (i+1) );
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth to provide different methods to find the runs, to print the runs between `(` and `)`, and to print longest runs using a helper class `Run` to store the data about the run: `start`, `length`, `value`:

```java
static class Run {
    int start;
    int length = 1;
    int value;
}

static List<Run> findRuns(int ... arr) {
    List<Run> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Run run = new Run();
    run.start = 0;
    run.value = arr[0];
    
    int max = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != run.value) {
            result.add(run);
            
            run = new Run();
            run.start = i;
            run.value = arr[i];
            
        } else {
            run.length++;
            if (max < run.length) {
                max = run.length;
            }
        }
    }
    result.add(run);
    System.out.println("Longest run: " + max);
    
    return result;
}
```

Printing method uses Stream API + `Collections.nCopies` to build runs

```java
static String printRuns(List<Run> runs) {
    return runs.stream()
        .map(r -> r.length > 1 
            ? "(" + String.join(" ", Collections.nCopies(r.length, Integer.toString(r.value))) + ")"
            : Integer.toString(r.value)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Similar printing of longest runs (which can be multiple)

```java
static String printLongestRuns(List<Run> runs) {
    int max = runs.stream().mapToInt(r -> r.length).max().orElse(-1);
    
    return runs.stream()
        .map(r -> r.length > 1
            ? (r.length == max ? "(" : "") 
                + String.join(" ", Collections.nCopies(r.length, Integer.toString(r.value))) 
                + (r.length == max ? ")" : "")
            : Integer.toString(r.value)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Tests

```java
System.out.println(printRuns(findRuns(1)));
System.out.println(printRuns(findRuns(2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 1)));
System.out.println(printLongestRuns(findRuns(2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 1)));
```

Output

```
Longest run: 1
1
Longest run: 4
(2 2) (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5 5 5) 6 3 1
Longest run: 4
2 2 5 5 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5 5 5) 6 3 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't learned how to use the Stream API in class so Ill take a look at what you have done and see what I can use

Comment: edit: The program works! I worked out the issues in the loops and submitted it thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

some errors to fix:

- your code needs an entry point where the program starts. java doesn't start at the top of the program. java instanciates all free* static variables(that are outside of functions within your class) and start execution at the first line inside a `public static void main(String[] args) { /*here*/ }` function. if you work inside an instance of your class (which you are not here) non-static free* variables will be instanciated within that instance. **TLDR: make the Scanner `static` aswell and add a `static void main(String[] args)` function.**
- in your for loop `for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)` you try to compare values `if(array[i] == array[i++])` which will lead to `if(array[array.length] == array[array.length+1])` in the last cycle and **crash your application with arrayoutofbounds-exception**
- if you create a function with a return type other than void like you did with `public static **int** findRun(int[]array)` you can't compile without errors if you don't provide the return variable (`return myint; // at the end of the function`)
- if you pass basic variables to functions they get copied in java, only objects from complex classes are treated as pointers. -> change `function randomNumbers(int[]array)` to `function randomNumbers()` and work with a static global array instead for example

also a word of warning:

- `Math.random()` is a **PSEUDO-random**-number generator between 0.000... and 0.999.... Select other real/secure random generators for security and science functions.

I hope this helps you to start. I don't think a working code would help you that much at this point. Once you get the java concepts you can definitely do it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include my entire program. I have the main method and code to prompt the user below the code that is above. I was forming the methods in the same class since they are static and thus do not need an object to run. I just need a working code...I have the rest formed in eclipse. Thank you for your tips tho, I will follow them.

Comment: sounds good. you need to fix the for-loop issue for sure. maybe capsulate your comparison within another if-clause that checks `if(i+1 <= array.length){ if(array[i] == array[i+1]){ ... } ... }`

Comment: And while i think about it remove all `i++` inside the for loop and replace them with `i+1` since you alter the cycle value this way (and skip some numbers). `i++` is short form for `i=i+1`.

Comment: edit: The program works! I worked out the issues in the loops and submitted it thank you all for your help!